# How to concatenate double quotes to be used in a start-process

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could anyone please give me a hand concatenating double quotes:

In this example, I'm writing a function to be used with Emacs on a Windows operating system.  File names with spaces need to be enclosed in double-quotes.

The buffer-file-name is:  `c:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/foo.tex`

I'm trying to use:

```
(setq pdf-file
  (concat "\"" (car (split-string (buffer-file-name) "\\.tex")) ".pdf" "\""))
```

When I call `(start-process "display" nil c:/SumatraPDF.exe pdf-file)`, the pdf viewer tries to open this instead:

```
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop"c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\foo.pdf"
```

---

**EDIT**:  This is the function that I was trying to modify.  As set forth in my answer below, the error was caused by my unwittingly having **double-double**-quoted the file name -- i.e., `start-process` treats a variable as being double-quoted, so there was never any need for me to concatenate another set of double quotes.

```
(defun latexmk ()
".latexmkrc contains the following entries:
  $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
  $pdf_mode = 1;
  $recorder = 0;
  $clean_ext = 'synctex.gz synctex.gz(busy) aux fdb_latexmk log';"
(interactive)
  (setq tex-file (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
  (setq base-file (car (split-string (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "\\.tex")))
  (setq pdf-file (concat base-file ".pdf"))
  (setq line (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))
  (setq sumatra "C:/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe")
  (setq tex-output (concat "*" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "*") )
  (setq latexmk "c:/texlive/2013/bin/win32/latexmk.exe")
  (setq latexmkrc "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Application Data/.emacs.d/.latexmkrc")
  (if (buffer-modified-p)
    (save-buffer))
  (delete-other-windows)
  (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (get-buffer-create tex-output))
  (with-current-buffer tex-output (erase-buffer))
  (start-process "tskill" nil "c:/WINDOWS/system32/tskill.exe" "SumatraPDF")
  (set-process-sentinel 
     (start-process "deep-clean" nil latexmk "-C" "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
     (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
       (set-process-sentinel 
         (start-process "compile" tex-output latexmk "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
         (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
       (set-process-sentinel 
           (start-process "displayline" nil sumatra "-forward-search" tex-file line pdf-file)
           (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
             (start-process "clean" nil latexmk "-c" "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
             (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer tex-file))
             (if (get-buffer-process (get-buffer tex-output))
               (process-kill-without-query (get-buffer-process (get-buffer tex-output))))
             (kill-buffer tex-output)
             (delete-other-windows)))))))))))
```

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you could do it simpler, with `replace-regexp-in-string` as @abo-abo suggests, your e-lisp code is OK and correctly places quotes around the filename.  I suppose that the problem is with calling the executable.  Shouldn't "c:/SumatraPDF.exe" be in quotes?  Have you tried without the extra quotes around the pdf file?

Comment: The pdf file can be displayed correctly (when *not* using double quotes) if there are no spaces in the folder names and if I only use the base-file name (without the absolute path), but double quotes are needed if spaces are present.  If there were a way to go to root as part of the `start-process`, then that might fix it.  The path to the executable works, and perhaps that is because there are no spaces in the file name of the executable -- if there were spaces, then that would probably need double quotes also.

Comment: I've updated the question with the working function, which I'm trying to modify to use the absolute file path with double quotes instead of just the base file name.

Comment: I've this bit of code left over from when I was using Windows:
`(shell-command (concat "pdflatex --shell-escape \"" (buffer-file-name) "\""))`.
Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly!  Thank you for the working example.  I looked at `shell-command` inside of `simple.el` and it uses `start-process`.  So it would appear that `start-process` automatically inserts quotes when a variable is used.  If I eliminate the double quotes from the variable and just let `start-process` do its thing, that seems to fix my function and enables me to use the absolute path with the full `buffer-file-name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start-process` treats a variable as if it were double-quoted.  In essence, my variable ended up being **double-double**-quoted -- which is what was preventing me from using the absolute path to the file.  So, in a nutshell, when using a variable with `start-process`, it need *not* be double-quoted.

Thank you to everyone who helped me to troubleshoot the issue -- greatly appreciated !

Here is the revised working function:

```
(defun latexmk ()
".latexmkrc contains the following entries:
  $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
  $pdf_mode = 1;
  $recorder = 0;
  $clean_ext = 'synctex.gz synctex.gz(busy) aux fdb_latexmk log';"
(interactive)
  (setq tex-file (buffer-file-name))
  (setq base-file (car (split-string (buffer-file-name) "\\.tex")))
  (setq pdf-file (concat base-file ".pdf"))
  (setq line (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))
  (setq sumatra "c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe")
  (setq tex-output (concat "*" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "*") )
  (setq latexmk "c:/texlive/2013/bin/win32/latexmk.exe")
  (setq latexmkrc "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Application Data/.emacs.d/.latexmkrc")
  (if (buffer-modified-p)
    (save-buffer))
  (delete-other-windows)
  (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (get-buffer-create tex-output))
  (with-current-buffer tex-output (erase-buffer))
  (start-process "tskill" nil "c:/WINDOWS/system32/tskill.exe" "SumatraPDF")
  (set-process-sentinel 
     (start-process "deep-clean" nil latexmk "-C" "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
     (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
       (set-process-sentinel 
         (start-process "compile" tex-output latexmk "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
         (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
          (start-process "displayline" nil sumatra "-forward-search" tex-file line pdf-file)
          (start-process "clean" nil latexmk "-c" "-r" latexmkrc tex-file)
          (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer tex-file))
          (if (get-buffer-process (get-buffer tex-output))
            (process-kill-without-query (get-buffer-process (get-buffer tex-output))))
          (kill-buffer tex-output)
          (delete-other-windows))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
 "\\.tex$"
 ".pdf"
 "c:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/foo.tex")
```

Comment: `(concat (car (split-string (buffer-file-name) "\\.tex")) ".pdf")` correctly changes the file-name, but the problem happens when I add the double quotes, which `start-process` needs when being used on a Windows operating system with file names that contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method of changing the file name, and thank you again for `(shell-command (concat "pdflatex --shell-escape \"" (buffer-file-name) "\""))`, which ultimately helped me to understand why my variable wasn't working correctly with `start-process`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq pdf-file (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".pdf"))
```

Also, if you need to quote an argument passed to a shell, use `shell-quote-argument`.

Comment: Thank you for the `shell-quote-argument` suggestion, and also for the alternative method of writing the form of `pdf-file` -- I'm sure that will come in handy.